# android progress circle is not showing up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner, progressdialog, android-progressbar

I am developing an android app and came across a trivial problem that i could not figure out.
I am trying to show progress circle after user clicks on search button. But some how I am not able to create progress bar with code I have written so far.

Code is as below..

In my fragment class below is code for search button click...

```
//create a progress dialog circle.
           spinner = (ProgressBar) searchByDoctor.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
           spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           spinner.setIndeterminate(true);
           List<DocInfoTO> docList = doctorService.findDocBySearchCriteria(docSearchInputTO);
           if(docList != null && docList.size() > 0)
           {
               //stop the progress cirlce as soon as we get the results.
               spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
               spinner.setIndeterminate(false);
               List<SearchResultDoctorRowItem> rowItems = new ArrayList<SearchResultDoctorRowItem>();
               for(DocInfoTO doc : docList)
               {
                   rowItems.add(YourDocUtil.setDoctorRowItemDto(doc));
               }
```

The xml is like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/android">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/enter_doc_name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:paddingTop="200dp"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="238dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:hint="@string/doctor_Name" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footerSearch"
        style="?metaButtonBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/black_overlay"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/searchDoc"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You code is fine. The reason you are not able to see the progress bar because it is going from `spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` state to `spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE)` too quickly. In short you progress bar is appearing and disappearing too quickly for you to notice it.

If this code `doctorService.findDocBySearchCriteria(docSearchInputTO)` took longer to execute you would be able to see your progress bar. `

Comment: Call to method findDocBySearchCriteria is actually bit longer as it incurs the server hit. I tried adding Thread.sleep(7000) for the sake of confirmation so that I can at least see the spinner spinning. But i has not helped me.

Comment: Try commenting out the spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE) for one build .

Comment: Is that because I am calling `doctorService.findDocBySearchCriteria(docSearchInputTO);`and spinner on same thread????

Comment: Nope, it is because it the appearing and disappearing too quickly.

Comment: Though it is taking time I am not seeing progress bar... Anyone has new thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have not called `spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE)` or `spinner.setVisibility(View.Invisible)` somewhere above the code you have written. It will cause the spinner to stop appearing.